# Rails 3.2 Asset Pipeline adds ?body=1 but serve empty resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I have an application on Heroku, which works correctly on my development environment. However, on Heroku, one of my javascripts file is served empty. It is the bootstrap file, provided by the bootstrap_for_rails gem

```
/assets/twitter/bootstrap-a43574b1a9d30434438a56d88ff10a70.js?body=1
 ==> Returns empty file???

/assets/twitter/bootstrap-a43574b1a9d30434438a56d88ff10a70.js
 ==> Returns the js file correctly
```

I'm using Rails 3.2 with asset pipeline, and using the Cedar Stack on Heroku.

Here's my production.rb assets settings

**Production.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.debug = true

config.assets.compress = false

config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true

# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

Quite simple application.js file :

**application.js**

```
 //= require twitter/bootstrap
```

**Gemfile**

```
 group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
   gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
 end
```

I am having trouble figuring out what could be the problematic piece. Heroku? Rails ? Sprockets? Configs?

I already tried changing much of my production.rb settings, including commenting out action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is by design. In looking at the actual bootstrap file (I'm looking here: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/twitter/bootstrap.js), there is no actual js in it. It is just signaling to sprockets, via the "//= require" lines, what .js files it should pull in and compile together. In development mode, these comments for sprockets are hidden on the front end since they're really just an implementation detail of sprockets/rails.

So in summary, when you attempt to view an (app/lib/vendor)/assets/javascript file that is full of nothing but multiple "//= require"s, that file will appear to be empty on the frontend because rails/sprockets hides that implementation detail from you on the front-end.

Comment: You might be right. The strange thing is when nothing is compiled and served, I do have all the other files served correctly, but my JS on my page using bootstrap is not working. I'll investigate more, but if you are right, my problem seems to be elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: No, the javascripts should work fine this way. If you haven't already, watch this RailsCast. It may be something simple you are overlooking. http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

Answer (score 0):

Why are you accessing the individual files directly? In production the idea of the pipeline is to merge all your individual files referenced in your application.js manifest file into a single application.js file.

Your code should only reference the application.css file via `javascript_include_tag`. In development this will show all the files included if you view source of your page as individual js files whilst in production what you should be seeing is a single js file like

/assets/application-46187b46e120ec79eabd082567660eb1.js

Comment: This is pre-production state let's say. I'm still debugging every components. I will certainly compile everything and compress it for production.

Comment: you posted your production.rb - your application is running in production mode on heroku unless you've change it...I dont understand what mean. This is what the pipeline does, it's doing exactly what it should do in production mode.

Comment: Well not serving an empty file. Every other JS (10+) got served correctly, even with the ?body=1 query params

Comment: view the source of http://kyan.com - that's what you should be seeing. The body parameter is added in development mode whilst production uses signatures.

Comment: When compiled in production, problem does not happen. It started to happen in development as well... can't find the root cause.

Answer (score -1):

I've had some issues with the assets group on Heroku. Trying moving it outside of it and see if that works.